# TypeError: tf.broadcastTo is not a function

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Using tensorflowjs (tfjs-node@1.2.3),

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
...
imageNetStats = tf.broadcastTo(imageNetStats, [h, w, 3])
```

gives error  TypeError: tf.broadcastTo is not a function

This function was working yesterday and nothing has changed.

Comment: What would you like to do ? Do you want to reshape  `imageNetStats` ?

Answer (score 0):

`broadcastTo` has been added to the API only since the version 1.5.x. This explains why the function is not found since you are using the version 1.2.3